# how to design overloaded member functions with const and volatile while designing API?

Tags: c++, api

Let's assume you are writing a small library or an API that will be distributed to other programes,
that means you never know how other programers will create objects: will such an object be const, volatile, const volatile or it will be just an plain object.

normaly when we declare some class we do it so:

```
class A // THIS CLASS DOES NOT SUPPORT ANYTHING
{
public:
    int get() { return x; }
private:
    int x;
};
```

however if you want your class to support const objects you'll overload member function with const qualificator:

```
class B // THIS CLASS SUPPORTS CONST OBJECTS
{
public:
    int get() { return x; }
    int get() const { return x; }
private:
    mutable int x;
};
```

more futer maybe we want also to support volatile but not const for our class:

```
class C // THIS CLASS SUPPORTS VOLATILE OBJECTS
{
public:
    int get() { return x; }
    int get() volatile { return x; }
private:
    int x;
};
```

BUT what if user will use a object that is const or volatile or
what if user will use a object that is volatile and const in same time?
then we should add support for that too!

```
class D // THIS CLASS SUPPORTS CONST, VOLATILE AND CONST VOLATILE OBJECTS
{
public:
    int get() { return x; }
    int get() const { return x; }
    int get() volatile { return x; }
    int get() const volatile { return x; }
private:
    mutable int x;
};
```

now let's see why would we want our class to have those 4 overloads:

```
// EXAMPLE
int main()
{
    // figure 1
    const A a ;
    a.get(); // ERROR

    // figure 2
    volatile B b;
    b.get(); // ERROR

    // figure 3
    const volatile C c;
    c.get(); // ERROR

    // figure 4 where we finaly created a super class capable of anything!!
    const volatile D d;
    d.get(); // NOW IS OK!

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

well in this last example (figure 4) we can be shore that our class is capable to be instatated of **any type**
that means other programers will not have problem to create volatile, const or volatile const object of your class!

my question is:
is it a good design practice to overlaod each method four times?
if not why not?

also if our class has let's say 20 methods then it will acctualy have 80 methods when you overload them all!

EDIT:

does real world API classes do such thing?
if not, then how would we create volatile or const volatile object of that class if let's say we have such need.

Comment: Having a `const` object is viable, but I doubt there will be many uses of `volatile`. Also, for things like a simple getter, I would always make my methods `const`.

Comment: as you said: "I doubt there will be many uses of volatile" at least one of them may want so, also "I would always make my methods const" and what if that method must change internal member? all methods can not be const, such class would be useles :D

Comment: I meant that I always make my simple, non-modifying methods, const. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion is that in the real world:

1. Volatile is not widely used, and when it is it modifies always basic types. But never objects, so you never need to override a volatile member function.
2. `const` should be added to the member functions, not thinking in whether it will be needed by a `const` client code, but think instead if the operation the member function does is conceptually constant. That is called *const correctness*:

   a. First of all, the function should do just one thing. Maybe one complex thing, but describable as a single concept.

   b. Then, ask yourself whether this thing the function does changes the *observable state* of the object. If it does, then the function should not be constant. And if it does not, then declare it as constant.

When a client code wants to use your class, it will have a `const` reference when it is not  allowed to modify the state of the object, and all will just work.

Note that I talked about the *observable state* of the object, not the actual contents of the member variables: that is an implementation detail.

Comment: Sometimes *pointers* to objects are volatile (volatile is most often used with built in types), and this does not require your method to be volatile. I never saw a use for those volatile modifiers (except http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403766 of course).

Comment: @AlexandreC That Alexandrescu technique is a smart abuse of a mostly useless language feature. So cool!